# Why ES6 modules can be tree shaked

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules, tree-shaking

I don't understand why ES6 modules can be easily tree shaked and commonjs `require`s can not. I read dozen of articles but none of them explains it in depth. The only thing, everybody is mentioning is the "static" nature of es6 modules in contrary to "dynamic nature" of commonjs modules.

I'm looking for in depth explanation why the es6 modules can be tree shaked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the static vs dynamic argument? What else are you looking for?

Comment: I just dont understand what do static and dynamic mean in this context.

Comment: Static means that the code can be analyzes without executing it. That allows tools like rollup to determine, without executing a module, which imports it depends on. CommonJS modules OTOH *can* by dynamic (nothing prevents you from doing `if (something) { require('foo'); }` so it's not possibly to know whether `foo` is needed or not until the code is executed, which means it always needs to be included in the bundle. Another part is that CommonJS allows you do do `require('foo/' + runtimeValue)` so the complete path is also only known at runtime.

Comment: Sure, I get it, but we can do dynamic imports() in ES6 also right? How is it different from dynamic require ?
+ can't we use something simmilar to webpack sideEffects when using commons modules?

Comment: @leszczu450 dynamic `import()` will be added as part of ES2020, it's not generally considered part of ES6 modules. And indeed, modules imported that way generally cannot be tree-shaken.

Comment: Oh, didn't know. One more thing in regard to this sentence "Static means that the code can be analyzes without executing it.". Who is doing this analysis and how? Is it webpack/rollup while parsing? How is the static anlysis perfomed by tooling?